# Foursquare API - Popular Venue by City

Tags: api, foursquare

Is there a way to use the Foursquare API to get the most popular venues for a specific city?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the boundaries of a city from google places api, then you can query with the venue/search method within that area, then sort by checkins count to get the most popular venues.